# Defining functions with pattern as argument

Tags: functions, function-construction, pattern-matching, argument-patterns

I want to define a function such that

```
f[18/17 h[y][z]] = 18/17  z
```

for any function `h[y][z]`.

I first tried with `f[___x_[y_][z_]___] :=  z` which returns

```
(* f[18/17 h[y][z]] =  z *)
```

How can I return any numeric coefficient in the pattern `___x_[y_][z_]___`?

Comment: `f[c_. h[_][z_]] := c z`?

Comment: thanks! What does this mean exactly? `c_.`

Comment: Just in case the coefficient is 1, look up `Default`.\